# How to load files and iterate with Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I know this is a simple question. However I can google more to find the answer But your answer can give different ideas to work on. I am trying to understand the new feature introduced in Java 8. As part of that, I have written some code to read the files in a directory and put them in List of InputStream. How can I simplify the following code with Java 8?

```
File[] gred_files = gred_directory.listFiles();

List<InputStream> gredInputStreamList = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

for(File gred_file: gred_files) {
if(gred_file.isFile()) {
    InputStream gredStream = new FileInputStream(gred_file);
    if (gredStream != null)
    {
        gredInputStreamList.add(gredStream);
    }
  }
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify by removing the `if (gredStream != null)` check. `new` can never create `null`, in the worst case it will raise an exception.

Comment: You don’t read the files, you’re only opening the files. What’s the purpose of that `List<InputStream>`?

Comment: @Holger Maybe to use them later. But you are going to the right direction: opening and using them should be in a tight loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<InputStream> gredInputStreamList  = Arrays.stream(gred_directory.listFiles())
    .filter(File::isFile)
    .map(FileInputStream::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I am not sure about the part of `.map(FileInputStream::new)`, however, as there is a checked exception. Maybe we'd need a helper method here which does

```
InputStream openStream(File file) {
    try {
        return new FileInputStream(gred_file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and you'd do `.map(WhateverClassThisIsIn::openStream)` here.

Or maybe even better

```
Optional<InputStream> openStream(File file) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(new FileInputStream(gred_file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

and

```
List<InputStream> gredInputStreamList  = Arrays.stream(gred_directory.listFiles())
    .filter(File::isFile)
    .map(WhateverClassThisIsIn::openStream)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

to avoid unnecessary `null` values. (Although, in such a tight loop, it won't matter.)

Comment: + I like your helper method ;)

Comment: Well, `.map(FileInputStream::new)` doesn’t work because of the checked exception, however, if it worked, the subsequent `.filter(o -> o != null)` was obsolete, as the result of the `new` operator can never be `null`.

Comment: @Holger That's right for the first code example, so I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
Arrays.stream(gred_files)
      .filter(File::isFile).map(file -> {
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return null;
        })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `.map(file -> new FileInputStream(file))` won't work because of the `IOException` which needs to be checked.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks :) Didn't see the Checked Exception part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
List<InputStream> list = Files.list(gred_directory.toPath())
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .map(path -> {
        try { return Files.newInputStream(path); }
        catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

though, it might be worth using the NIO API in the first place instead of starting with a `File`.

But even more questionable is the desire the get a `List<InputStream>`. A `List` is no end in itself, so if you plan to read the files, you should do that directly in the Stream operation. Depending on the underlying system, there might be a limitation on how many files can be open simultaneously. If you process and close the Stream in subsequent operations of a single Stream pipeline, each file will be processed completely before opening the next one.

Depending on the actual operation, you might even skip dealing with `InputStream`s:

```
List<byte[]> list = Files.list(gred_directory.toPath())
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .map(path -> {
        try { return Files.readAllBytes(path); }
        catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```